# how to use order by clause using Stuff in sql

Tags: sql-server

```
stuff(( select distinct  ',',Convert(varchar(256),y.RoomPlanID)
from(
    select  x.RoomPlanID ,x.RoomPlanHierarchy from (select  utblConfigDestRoomRates.RoomPlanID,utblMstRoomPlans.RoomPlanHierarchy
                            FROM utblConfigDestRoomRates inner
                            JOIN utblMstRoomPlans on utblConfigDestRoomRates.RoomPlanID=utblMstRoomPlans.RoomPlanId
                            WHERE PropertyTypeID=1
                            AND BusinessID='AAAA' 
                            AND('25-Aug-2015' BETWEEN DateEffective AND DateEnd) 
                            AND StarRank=3     group by RoomPlanHierarchy order by RoomPlanHierarchy asc
                            ) x
                             --order by
                             -- x.RoomPlanHierarchy
                              )y 
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: you mean ms sql server, right? it is tagged mysql. Not much more than a title to go on.

Comment: Try moving ordering after `y` just before `for xml` clause.

Comment: the question is formulated very poor

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL) function. I assume that order to x.RoomPlanHierarchy like this

```
stuff(( select distinct  ',',Convert(varchar(256),y.RoomPlanID)
from(
    select  x.RoomPlanID ,x.RoomPlanHierarchy,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.RoomPlanHierarchy asc) AS Row from (select  utblConfigDestRoomRates.RoomPlanID,utblMstRoomPlans.RoomPlanHierarchy
                            FROM utblConfigDestRoomRates inner
                            JOIN utblMstRoomPlans on utblConfigDestRoomRates.RoomPlanID=utblMstRoomPlans.RoomPlanId
                            WHERE PropertyTypeID=1
                            AND BusinessID='AAAA' 
                            AND('25-Aug-2015' BETWEEN DateEffective AND DateEnd) 
                            AND StarRank=3     group by RoomPlanHierarchy 
                            ) x
                             --order by
                             -- x.RoomPlanHierarchy
                              )y 
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Column 'utblConfigDestRoomRates.RoomPlanID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score -2):

--Format it in SQL

```
 (
SELECT
     stuff(
     (
SELECT
            '' + a.col_name ,
           '' + Replace(CAST(a.pos as VARCHAR), a.pos, '') + '"' 
        FROM
             (
              SELECT
                     CAST (',' + db_column_name + ' AS "' + REPLACE(label_tag, '.', '_') AS nvarchar (4000) ) AS col_name,
                     row_number() over (partition BY RIGHT(entity, CHARINDEX('.', (REVERSE(entity)) ) - 1) ORDER BY db_column_name) AS pos
                FROM
                     table1 AS ex
                JOIN
                     table2 AS ef
                  ON
                     ef.col1 = ex.col1
               WHERE
                     entity LIKE '%string%')a FOR xml path('')) , 1, 1, '' ) )
```